# The cpu_time obtained by proc_pid_rusage does not meet expectations on the macOS M1 chip

Tags: c++, macos, apple-m1

At present, I need to calculate the cpu usage of a certain process on the macOS platform (the target process is not directly related to the current process). I use the [proc_pid_rusage](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2422.1.72/libsyscall/wrappers/libproc/libproc.h.auto.html) API. The calculation method is to call it every once in a while, and then calculate this section The difference between ri_user_time and ri_system_time of the time. So as to calculate the percentage of cpu usage.

I used it on a macOS system with non-M1 chip, and the results were in line with expectations (basically the same as what I saw on the activity monitor), but recently I found that the value obtained on the macOS system with the M1 chip is small. For example, **one of my processes that consumes 30+% of the cpu(from activity monitor) is less than 1%**.

I provide a demo code, you can directly create a new project to run:

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  SimpleMonitor
//
//  Created by m1 on 2021/2/23.
//
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libproc.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>         // std::this_thread::sleep_for
#include <chrono>         // std::chrono::seconds

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "run simple monitor!\n";
    
    // TODO: change process id:
    int64_t pid = 12483;

    struct rusage_info_v4 ru;
    struct rusage_info_v4 ru2;

    int64_t success = (int64_t)proc_pid_rusage((pid_t)pid, RUSAGE_INFO_V4, (rusage_info_t *)&ru);
    
    if (success != 0) {
        std::cout << "get cpu time fail \n";
        return 0;
    }
    
    std::cout<<"getProcessPerformance, pid=" + std::to_string(pid) + " ru.ri_user_time=" + std::to_string(ru.ri_user_time) + " ru.ri_system_time=" + std::to_string(ru.ri_system_time)<<std::endl;

    std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(10));
    
    int64_t success2 = (int64_t)proc_pid_rusage((pid_t)pid, RUSAGE_INFO_V4, (rusage_info_t *)&ru2);
    
    if (success2 != 0) {
        std::cout << "get cpu time fail \n";
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout<<"getProcessPerformance, pid=" + std::to_string(pid) + " ru2.ri_user_time=" + std::to_string(ru2.ri_user_time) + " ru2.ri_system_time=" + std::to_string(ru2.ri_system_time)<<std::endl;
    
    int64_t cpu_time = ru2.ri_user_time - ru.ri_user_time + ru2.ri_system_time - ru.ri_system_time;

    // percentage:
    double cpu_usage = (double)cpu_time / 10 / 1000000000 * 100 ;
    
    std::cout<<pid<<" cpu usage: "<<cpu_usage<<std::endl;

}
```

Here I want to know whether there is a problem with my calculation method, if there is no problem, how can I handle the inaccurate results on the M1 chip macOS system?

Comment: Other than reporting the issue to Apple? No other choice, smells like a bug on the OSX end. No integer underflow issues or alike visible.

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't mix `RUSAGE_INFO_V0` and `RUSAGE_INFO_V4`? You ask for `RUSAGE_INFO_V0` but supply a `rusage_info_v4` struct. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks. In fact, I used RUSAGE_INFO_V4 at the beginning. The problem is the same, but I tried RUSAGE_INFO_V0 later and pasted a problematic code, which has been corrected.

Comment: How to compile it? Simple `gcc main.cpp -o main` gives a lot of "symbol not found" errors.

Answer (score 3):

You have to multiply the CPU usage by some constant.
Here are some snippets of code from a diff.

```cpp
#include <mach/mach_time.h>

// ...

mach_timebase_info_data_t sTimebase;
mach_timebase_info(&sTimebase);
timebase_to_ns = (double)sTimebase.numer / (double)sTimebase.denom;

// ...

syscpu.total = task_info.ptinfo.pti_total_system* timebase_to_ns/ 1000000;
usercpu.total = task_info.ptinfo.pti_total_user* timebase_to_ns / 1000000;
```